# having an error reading from a file in java

Tags: java

need help fixing this error. I am trying to print out the array length of string countryNames.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1516)
at CSVReader.setUp(CSVReader.java:25)
at CSVReader.<init>(CSVReader.java:16)
at TestCSVReader.main(TestCSVReader.java:16)
```

I am reading from a cvs file and i keep getting the error above. Below is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CSVReader {
//String countryNames;
String[] countryNames;
int yearLabels;
int[] yearNum;
 double cellularDataTable;
 double[][] tables;
Scanner scan;

public CSVReader(String filename)// throws FileNotFoundException 
{ 
    setUp(filename);
}
private void setUp(String filename) //throws FileNotFoundException
{
    File file = new File(filename);
    try{
        String input="";
        scan = new Scanner(file);
        scan.nextLine();
        while((input=scan.nextLine())!=null)
        {
            String[] countryNames = input.split(",");
            //int a = Integer.parseInt(countryNames[1]);
            System.out.println(countryNames[0]);
            //System.out.println(a);
        }
        scan.close();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
    public String[] getCountryNames()
{
    return countryNames;
}
```

Below is my TestCSV class file:

```
public class TestCSVReader {

/**
 * Includes test examples for class CSVReader.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) 
{   
    final String FILENAME = "data/cellular.csv";    // Directory path for Mac OS X
    //final String FILENAME = "data\cellular.csv";  // Directory path for Windows OS (i.e. Operating System)


    CSVReader parser = new CSVReader(FILENAME);

    String [] countryNames = parser.getCountryNames();
    System.out.println(countryNames.length);
    }
```

my csv file looks like this below: This is a summary as i did not want to print out the entire 252 countries. Basically i take in 252 countries and store it in a string array, the years and store them in an int array and stats of cellular data of each country in a 2d double array. I am new to programming and would like to know if i am heading in the right direction and if not how would you country name in a string array, the years in an int. and stats in a 2d double array.

cvs file looks like this:

```
World Development Indicators
Number of countries,252
Country  Name,1960,1961,1962,1963,1964,1965,1966,1967,1968,1969,1970,1971,1972,1973,1974,1975,1976,1977,1978,1979,1980,1981,1982,1983,1984,1985,1986,1987,1988,1989,1990,1991,1992,1993,1994,1995,1996,1997,1998,1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012
 Aruba,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.029310471,0,0,2.138784453,3.605985937,3.98141538,6.16435217,13.48254011,16.50927821,57.05427692,65.05605558,72.10431377,99.64250268,103.3849507,108.1325002,112.2180618,119.2038996,126.2103374,129.72824,0,131.8565401
Andorra,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1.307211734,1.278625641,1.250259142,4.424155104,8.538444783,13.44671556,22.12730607,32.14530928,35.99902139,43.27794118,45.77115817,68.60251444,73.82494308,79.48487497,84.27763597,78.1171579,80.2836099,82.06181111,84.06818386,83.53432222,81.50204186
 Afghanistan,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.112598381,0.865196277,2.498055472,4.826865367,9.833164022,17.71624331,29.22037376,37.89493697,45.77817474,60.32631999,60.35299258
```

Comment: You may check if there is another line first, before you try to read it. So `while(scanner.hasNextLine())` instead of `while((input=scan.nextLine())!=null)` could help you.

Comment: this is the answer, so just write it as answer ;)

Comment: @Tom thanks. Now i want to initialize the string[] countryNames to 252. How would you go about that

Comment: @user2738145 The line `String[] countryNames = input.split(",");` creates a new variable `countryNames` that is valid in the loop body. After each iteration this variable will be deleted/overwritten. I recommend using a `List` and use the line `countryNames.add(data[0])` with `String[] data = input.split(",");` and the countryNames declared as `List<String> countryNames = new ArrayList<>();` as a class field.

Comment: @Tom oh ok but the requirement was not to use list as the professor hasn't taught that yet. Just barely finished on arrays and required to use a 1d array to store the countries, 1d array to store the years and 2d array to store the country with their stats

Comment: @user2738145 As I can see, you're skipping the first line of your CSV file. But you should also treat the second line differently (the line that contains the amount of countries). You can create a method `public int getAmount(Scanner in)` and in there you can read the second line `String[] data = in.nextLine()` and return the amount by using `return Integer.parseInt(data[data.length-1]);`. This will return the `252`. Now you can use `countryNames = new String[getAmount(scan)];`. And you should consider changing the `while` loop to a `for` with the amount as the termination statement.

Comment: @Tom. I just saw your comment. i have a method public String[] getCountryNames() that should return all the country names. so in that method my approach was Number of countries [number of countries]"
where [number of countries] stands for a number.  Then, parse the line and store [number of countries] into the variable "numberOfCountries". (Don't forget to convert [number of countries], which is a String, to an integer.) I think its similar to your idea you mentioned above. I have a had time implementing it in code if you could show an example that will really help

Comment: @Tom plus i have a similar approach to get the years from the csv file. and i have another method called public int[] getYearLables. where i read the CSV file one line at a time until you reach line starting with "Country Name".  The format of this line is: "Country Name,[year],[year]"
where [year] is an integer, which i will use as the label for a year.For example: "Country Name,1960,1961,1962". I just need some example in code to guide me and i appreciate your help a lot.

Comment: @user2738145 I guess it is much better to create a new question for this new problem. Doing that in the comments is cumbersome.

Comment: @Tom sorry for late reply. I posted a new topic about the question. the topic is called reading a string, an int and double from a csv file. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line `while((input=scan.nextLine())!=null)` tries to read separate lines from the file until `input` becomes `null`. But `nextLine()` will throw an exception if there are no more lines available.

To avoid this, change your code to the following

```
//String input=""; // this line is obsolete
scan = new Scanner(file);
scan.nextLine();
while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
    final String input = scan.nextLine(); // read the line after the check (to make sure there is a line available)
    String[] countryNames = input.split(",");
    //int a = Integer.parseInt(countryNames[1]);
    System.out.println(countryNames[0]);
    //System.out.println(a);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem posed in the thread has been solved with

```
while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
```

But there's another problem that you'll find in your code. Inside the loop, you've created a local variable countryNames[], which isn't related with the String[] countryNames declared in the class.

I recommend you to change the declaration just like that:

```
public class CSVReader {     
    List<String> countryNames;
```

And initialize it in the constructor of the class:

```
public CSVReader(String filename)// throws FileNotFoundException 
{ 
    countryNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    setUp(filename);   
}
```

ArrayList allows you to add values dynamically. So, inside the loop, you must add each country name to this ArrayList:

```
String[] countryValues = input.split(",");
countryNames.add(countryValues[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe like this, you have a specific method to test if scan has more element to read

```
String input="";
scan = new Scanner(file);
scan.nextLine();
while(scan.hasNext())
{
    input=scan.nextLine();
    String[] countryNames = input.split(",");
    //int a = Integer.parseInt(countryNames[1]);
    System.out.println(countryNames[0]);
    //System.out.println(a);
}
scan.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think countryNames array is null. try to initialize it before adding data. 
debug your code and check countryNames...

```
String[] countryNames = new String[...]
```

if you don't know length of array, you had better use Arraylist. 
(when using Arraylist,you don't have to initialize first.)